# Global variable in Jest Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, global-variables, jestjs

I am new to Jest and trying to write some unit tests for my existing React App. I have a global variable `window.CONFIG` which stores some configurations which are used at different places in app. This variable is initialised in a script tag of landing HTML page

Now I am trying to write a test of an helper function which depends on this `window.CONFIG` and it is always undefined when accesses

Here is the code:

config.js

```
export default window.CONFIG;
```

app/helper.js

```
import config from "../config";

export default  {
  getCompanyURL(company) {
    return config.baseUrl + "/companies/" + company.id;
  },
}
```

_ *tests* _/helpers-test.js

```
jest.dontMock('../app/helpers.js');

var helper = require('../app/helpers.js').default;

describe('Get company URL', function() {

 it('returns company url with company id appended', function() {
   expect(companies.getCompanyURL({id:     1})).toBe('test_base_url/companies/1');
 });
});
```

`config` for `Get Company Url` is always undefined. As the browser landing page is not loaded `window.CONFIG` is not initialised. How can I mock this `config` module in my unit test in Jest?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this helps you or not but you can put global variables directly into your `package.json`

```
"jest":{
  "globals": {
    "config": {"foo":"bar"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • coveragePathIgnorePatterns
  • extraGlobals
  • globalSetup
  • globalTeardown
  • moduleNameMapper
  • resetMocks
  • resetModules
  • snapshotSerializers
  • transform
  • transformIgnorePatterns
  • watchPathIgnorePatterns.

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:,This is what i get when i updated the package.json, any idea on this or do i need to eject the module

Answer (score 1):

In a recent project (using create-react-app, jest, react testing library and TypeScript), I was using the variable `globalThis._env_`.

All my attempts to override it in the files containing the tests failed, but adding it to `setupTests.ts` worked in the end:

```
// in setuTests.ts
globalThis._env_ = {
    UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_MB: '5'
};
```

(I think `setupTests.js` / `setupTests.ts` is a react testing library thing - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#react-testing-library )

Comment: Like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58809134/1143126

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a manual mock of `config.js` in `__mocks__` directory as follows:

```
let configMock = jest.genMockFromModule('../config');
let __mockConfig = {};

__mockConfig.baseUrl = "test_base_url/";

configMock = __mockConfig;

export default configMock;
```

Comment: how do you access it window.config, so in any test case if you put console.log(window.config.baseUrl) => will be getting the "test_base_url/"