# jest global variable example

Tags: jestjs

Can someone give an example on how to use jest globals?

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true,
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Do I specify the globals in the package.json file or do I create a folder with a js file where the globals should be defined?

Thanks

Comment: Source: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yep.  You put the globals in the package.json.  For example, here's an excerpt from the default react-native jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "globals": {
       "__DEV__": true,
       "__RCTProfileIsProfiling": false
     },
     ...
},
```

This will make the variables available globally when the tests are run.

Comment: You can also access the global variables like `global.__DEV__`, if needed.

Comment: A cleaner way to add globals would be to set `"setupFiles": "<rootDir>/private/jest/setup.js"` in package.json, and then create a file that sets `global.__DEV__ = true`. This pattern is helpful for making 3rd party libraries available as globals to Jest tests as well (like Backbone, jQuery, lodash, etc.) - eg. `global.Backbone = require('backbone');`

Comment: Thanks @nickang, your comment is more useful, why don't you add it as an answer.

Comment: How can i add the window object in this, when i tried it was showing to eject for adding other options so i need to have a global variable inside window object , like window._config_.URL = 'http://www.example.com', how should i add it in the jest inside package.json

Answer (score 37):

A cleaner way to add globals would be to set `"setupFiles": "<rootDir>/private/jest/setup.js"` in package.json, and then create a setup.js file that sets `global.__DEV__ = true`.

This pattern is helpful for making 3rd party libraries available as globals to Jest tests as well (like Backbone, jQuery, lodash, etc.) - eg. `global.Backbone = require('backbone');` and so on.

*(Re-submitting this as an answer as it was previously just a comment under Michael Helvey's answer.)*

Comment: global.__DEV__ is just [an example from documentation for the globals parameter](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object), which only enables to set accessible globals values from jest.config.js.

[setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) are run before every test file, and globals defined in them can be accessed from test files.

[globalSetup](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string) is run before all test files; globals defined inside cannot be accessed from test files, and unfortunately from setupFiles neither.

Comment: quick heads-up: 
`setupFiles` need to be defined as an array

Answer (score 11):

For me using the Jest config file worked much better because it is a Javascript file itself so it gives full freedom:

After running `jest --init` in your folder, in the `jest.config.js` file Jest makes, scroll down to find:

```
// A set of global variables that need to be available in all test environments
// globals: {},
```

Uncomment the second line and put all your globals in there.

Comment: How do I put functions in globals though?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using create-react-app, you must use the `src/setupTests.js` file instead of pointing to a file via setupFiles in the package.json file.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#srcsetuptestsjs

In the `src/setupTests.js` file, you can define globals like so:

```
global.TIMEOUT = 3000;
```

Comment: this worked for me :) after several search thanks steve :)

Answer (score 1):

To share object variables (not only primitives as with configuration's globals property), you can use the [testEnvironment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) property.

More explanations here in [Jest's Git](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7184#issuecomment-769045405)