# Adding the properties to the window object and using it before the import of components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a Home component, so I am writing a test case for the component the problem is inside the Home Component I am requiring a config.js file and multiple components which inside they use config.js

The file is basically the configuration for the application.

So the values comes from `window._config_` object, so to add the properties in my test case. I have tried the below approach.

```
import React from "react";
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Home from "..";

describe("Home Page", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        window._config_ = {
            URL: "http://www.sample.com",
        };
    });
    it("should render Home Page", () => {
        console.log("here", window._env_);
        const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

});
```

So since the Home component is imported at the top, it will import the
related config files since inside the describe block only I am adding the
properties

In the above case I am getting the error as  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'URL' of undefined`

If I comment Home component its working, so I have tried importing Home inside the `'it'` block but for import should be done at the top level, so then I tried using common js require way but that's giving me the below error:

```
it("should render Home Page", () => {
    console.log("here", window._env_);
    const Home = require("..");
    const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
}


ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only with custom components, but the provided element type was `object`.
```

I am using CRA for React app.

How should I solve this?

### Update

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060295/jest-global-variable-example) also but how should I add it, when I added window inside global it says

```
Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • coveragePathIgnorePatterns
  • extraGlobals
  • globalSetup
  • globalTeardown
  • moduleNameMapper
  • resetMocks
  • resetModules
  • snapshotSerializers
  • transform
  • transformIgnorePatterns
  • watchPathIgnorePatterns.

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out, so you can add the global variables in setupTests.js

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

global.config = {
    URL: "http://www.example.com",
};
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

And in every test file you can access like this

```
it("should render Home Page", () => {
        console.log("here", window.config.URL);
        const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
```