# Typescript jest global variable example

Tags: typescript, jestjs

It is the same question, as correctly answered here [jest global variable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060295/jest-global-variable-example) , but the concern is Typescript.

```
console.log(__DEV__);
```

Results in:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name __DEV__.
```

The global var `__DEV__` is defined in package.json as:

```
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    }
  }
```

Has anybody a solution or work around?

Relevant jest documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/next/configuration#globals-object

Answer (score 3):

in ts-jest it's necessary to wrap some config values with "ts-jest":

```
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "__DEV__": true
      }
    }
  }
```

and can access in code with:

```
console.log((global as any).__DEV__
```

Found the answer here https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/

Comment: It would be nice if the `ts-jest` docs link point to the section where `globals` is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One proper solution is to write a .d.ts which introduces `declare` of global variable, and let tsconfig.json inclues this .d.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that proper solution is to create your custom.d.ts file and declare a global variable there.

[Here is how to do that](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-declare-global-variable#:%7E:text=To%20declare%20a%20global%20variable,the%20necessary%20properties%20or%20methods.)