# Declare global variable in TypeScript / NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to define a global variable `mockedCrossFetch` so that my test-cases can easily use it to mock responses:

```
jest.mock("cross-fetch");
import fetch from "cross-fetch"

declare global {
    let mockedCrossFetch: jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch>;
}

globalThis.mockedCrossFetch = fetch as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch>;
```

The compiler complains with:

```
Property 'mockedCrossFetch' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
```

For sure, I can just do

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
(globalThis as any).mockedCrossFetch = fetch as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch>;
```

But, what's the right approach to declare and define a global variable?

Comment: Refer here might be duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060295/jest-global-variable-example